# Open New Window from aspx page from *any* URL

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, iis

Is there any way to configure IIS or Web app to automatically open a new window when a hyperlink is clicked?  My issue isn't as trivial as it sounds, let me explain... I understand you can use JavaScript or `target="_blank"` in the anchor tag, but I don't always know when an anchor tag might be listed on the page...

The reason is that it's a user forum, think of stack overflow ;) where a user might enter a URL (allowed) and it's not necessarily known, or it was entered aeons ago and there is no way to tell.

I'm pretty sure the answer is no and I'll just have to analyze for URLs when the post/entry is being saved and convert it to do this then.

Comment: Or I suppose I could analyze HTML content being written to the page for a URL and then add the appropriate code...  hmmm...  there has to be someone who has tried this already and discovered some nifty pattern to solve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<base target='_blank'>  <!-- Here's the interesting bit -->
</head>
<body>
<p><a href='http://google.com'>New window!</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course that really will do **all** links - if you want a link to be an exception to the rule, and to open in the current window, do this:

```
<p><a href='http://google.com' target='_self'>Not new window!</a></p>
```

Comment: +1, Knew about the base tag, but never knew you could add the target attribute. Nice.

Comment: Cool.  I pretty much know about all of the links I create programatically on my page (i.e. urlrewriting, etc...) so I can easily add the target="_self" tag to those!  Thanks for a simple solution - completely didn't even consider HTML to have the answer lol.

Answer (score 4):

IIS wouldn't have anything to do with it - short of writing a filter that would rewrite all your links. I'd suggest JQuery, where it should be as easy as:

```
$(function() {
    $('A').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Great solution too!  Nifty for off setting the processing to the client side via javascript!  I guess the <base> tag does this too.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an HTTP Module which catches the ReleaseRequestState event. Then you would attach a filter to your HttpResponse. The filter could search for `<a>` tags and add the `target='_blank'` to those which don't already have them.

Comment: Cool idea, adds processing to the server, but nice to see a third way to get it done, thanks for all the replices guys, you all rock!!